# Property of morphism can be checked on a general open affine contained within target

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In the first few exercises for Chapter 2, Part 3 of Hartshorne's book on schemes there are several results that have the general shape as follows:

> Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes such that $Y$ has a cover by
>   open affines $V_i = \text{Spec}(B_i)$, each of whose preimages under $f$ has some property $P$,
>   and then say $f$ has property $P'$. Then $f$ has property $P'$ if and
>   only if for every open affine $V = \text{Spec}(B)\subseteq Y$ has
>   property $P$.

Some examples:

1. $P'$ could be "locally of finite type" and $P$ could be "$f^{-1}(V)$ can be covered by affine open subsets $U_i = \text{Spec}(A_i)$ where each $A_i$ is a finitely generated $B$-algebra;
2. $P'$ could be "quasi-compact" and $P$ could be "$f^{-1}(V)$ is quasi-compact";
3. $P'$ could be "finite" and $P$ could be "$f^{-1}(V) = \text{Spec}(A)$ is affine and $A$ is a finitely generated $B$-module".

In each case the reverse direction is just a matter of applying the definitions and noting every scheme $Y$ has a covering of open affines. The forward directions, though, seem to be more tricky to prove. I have found Case 2 above to be relatively easy to prove whilst Cases 1 and 3 were difficult (I also opened a bounty on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803636/question-on-morphism-locally-of-finite-type) about Case 1 because I think a good answer to this would be helpful for many people).

As an example for Case 3, I started by writing $V = \bigcup_{i\in I} (V\cap V_i)$ for the supplied affine covering $V_i = \text{Spec}(B_i)$. Then $f^{-1}(V_i) = \text{Spec}(A_i)$ and $A_i$ is a finite $B_i$-module. For each $v\in V$ we can find an index $i(v)$ and a principal open set $v\in W_v \subseteq V\cap V_{i(v)}$. Since $V$ is affine it is quasicompact, so we can pick finitely many $v_1, \dots, v_n \in V$ such that

$$V = \bigcup_{j=1}^n W_{v_j}$$

The preimages of the affines are principal open sets, so $f^{-1}(V)$ is a finite union of principal opens and is thus affine, say $f^{-1} (V) = \text{Spec}(A)$. But I don't know how to relate this data back to also get that $A$ is a finite $B$-module.

Is there a general strategy for these kinds of proofs (of the forward direction), or do the proofs vary significantly depending on the property? And can anyone suggest how to finish this proof in Case 3?

Comment: I think what you are after is what Vakil calls the 'affine communication lemma' :) See section 5.3 here: http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGdec2915public.pdf

Comment: @AlexYoucis this really is exactly what I needed (plus the proposition before it). Thanks for directing me here!